# Integration of nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In Gelfand Fomin well known Calculus of Variations text, when dealing with the isoperimetric problem in the upper half plane they obtain the differential equation 
$$ 
x+\lambda\frac{y'(x)}{\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2}}=C_1
$$
with $C_1$ an arbitrary constant. They conclude in one line that integration of this gives the (expected) solution 
$$
(x-C_1)^2+(y-C_2)^2=\lambda^2.
$$
I really haven't been able to see how the integration is performed. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Solve for $y'(x)$ and find $y(x)$ using a substitution to compute the indefinite integral.